# Getting 'NaN' while trying to convert a string of date to milliseconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

Tried this:

1.

```js
const today = new Date('28.08.2020');
const milliseconds = today.getTime();
```

2. 

```js
const today = Date.parse("28.08.2020")
```

3. 

```js
var today = new Date('28.08.2020');
var milliseconds = today.getMilliseconds();
```

Getting `NaN` while trying to convert a string of date to milliseconds

Comment: use Ymd formate as `new Date('2020.08.28')` OR you can use moment js

Comment: @DevsiOdedra—no, don't do that, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 2):

Better to change date format to `YYYY-MM-DD` as suggested in other answer

Or you can do something like this

```js
 var from = '28.08.2020'.split(".");
    var today = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]);
    const milliseconds = today.getTime();

    console.log(milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the incorrect format. If you get the date from backend you should convert it.

```js
    const date = '28.08.2020';

    const [day, month, year] = date.split('.');

    const validDate = new Date();

    validDate.setFullYear(year);
    validDate.setDate(day);
    validDate.setMonth(month);

    // or just 
    const validDate2 = new Date(year, month, day);

    const milliseconds = validDate.getTime();
    const milliseconds2 = validDate2.getTime();
    
    console.log(milliseconds)
    console.log(milliseconds2)
```

After this conversion you can use the date as you want

Comment: if it helped, please mark as correct, in accordance that my answer was the first) thank you, Have a nice day)

Comment: Close, but needs `month - 1` in the constructor. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you do not want to manually parse the string, you could try to use `moment` library, which allows one to provide custom dateString patterns used for parsing the date, like demonstrated below

```js
const dateString = '28.08.2020';

const date = moment(dateString, "DD.MM.YYYY");

console.log("date", date); // displayed zulu time might be different than your local timezone
console.log("milliseconds", date.valueOf());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Please take a note that moment will accept the date in your local timezone, which may pose some issues. If you want to make up for it, you should look up `moment-timezone` library

Comment: It shows inaccurate value

Comment: as i explained below the snipet, function assumes the datestring you pass is in your localtimezone, while just logging it converts it to zulu time.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, in that case you can change the imput to the "yyyy-mm-dd", is that a posibility?

```
const date = '28.08.2020';
let dateFromat = date.split('.');
dateFromat = `${dateFromat[2]}-${dateFromat[1]}-${dateFromat[0]}`;
const today = new Date(dateFromat);
const milliseconds = today.getTime();
```

output: 1598572800000

Comment: '28.08.2020' should be parsed as local, '2020-08-28' will be parsed as UTC.

Answer (score -2):

the dating format is wrong.

new Date('2020-08-28') should work

Comment: I need to convert exactly the format I have asked for.

Comment: '28.08.2020' should be parsed as local, '2020-08-28' will be parsed as UTC.